# How to get user role in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

How to get user role in Yii2?

I searched and read [Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html) but I didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can get Roles for an user by using [getRolesByUser](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-managerinterface.html#getRolesByUser%28%29-detail) function

You can use it like this

```
\Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($user_id);
```

Comment: Thanks man. It's work for me. Also I use **User::findByUsername($user_name)->getId()** to pass id to **getRolesByUser()** function

Comment: if you want to get role name as string not array, use this: 
` $userRole = array_keys(Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($user_Id))‌​[0] `

Comment: If you are using `defaultRoles` it will return those as well regardless of whether there are any rules that would effectively not allow them to take on those roles!

Answer (score 21):

You can use:

```
Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId());
```

Comment: but this returns the array of all roles and not the user role.

Comment: @AwaisMustafa I this you should check again, because getRolesByUser(Yii::$app->user->getId()) will return only the roles of that user.

Comment: @AwaisMustafa Is that because you are using `defaultRoles`? If so it seems like the rules are not being applied and hence you will see those default roles regardless....

Answer (score 10):

I use :

```
if (\Yii::$app->authManager-> getAssignment($role,$rule_id))
```

for filtering `user id` and `role` in rbac, More details on [Yii2 Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-managerinterface.html#getAssignment()-detail)

Comment: The parameter passed should not be $rule_id but $user_id. Minor small typo according to documentation. Thanks anyway. I have used it in my controller. I have voted you up.

Answer (score 1):

One more example how to get user role:
`Yii::$app->getUser()->identity->role;`
It works if you have column with name "role" in your user table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
 $user =[];
 $userAssigned = Yii::$app->authManager->getAssignments(user_id);
 foreach($userAssigned as $userAssign){
      $user[] = $userAssign->roleName;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [amnah/yii2-user](https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user) module, you can use this:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->role->name
```

It will give you the current user role name

Answer (score 0):

The good and more visual decision will be setting constants of all roles.

```
$userID = $user->getId();
array_keys(Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser($userID))[0] == User::ROLE_NAME
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good. Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can get role of the user by using createcommand.

```
    $roleModel = Yii::$app->db
    ->createCommand("Select * from auth_assignment where user_id='889'")
    ->queryOne();

    echo $roleModel['item_name'];
```

This will you user's role in auth assignment. Now you can check that if user is admin or editor or member.

Comment: Its much easier to use the methods the framework has to verify a role (accepted answer), than making a query to the database and needing to verify manually

Comment: i faced this issue that within the code, i tried alot to get a the role name of the admi nuser but i was successfull with this query so thats why i have shared this so that it may helps any one else

Comment: And what if the roles are stored not in db, but in redis (for example). This is not viable approach at all.