# Yii2: Hide search results based on permission

Tags: yii2, rbac

In my table I have:

```
PRODUCT
id_product
name
status
```

Where the status assumes the following values:

```
1 (Active)
2 (Inactive)
3 (Archived)
```

In the Product index view, I want the user to see certain statuses based on the permissions. Example:

- Administrator sees records with statuses 1, 2, and 3.
- Moderator views: 1 and 2
- User views: 1

How can I do this? What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add conditions to your search model (I guess you have a ProductSearch.php file) so that results will be filtered based on user's role.

I've never used Yii's RBAC but I suppose you have a method to get user role, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25248246/4338862

So in your search model I would add, after grid filtering conditions, one or more conditions:

```
if($isUser) {     
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'status' => 1,
    ]);
}
elseif($isModerator) {
    $query->andFilterWhere(['or',
       ['status' => 1],
       ['status' => 2]
    ]);
}
```

I can give you a more detailed answer if you need it.

Comment: Obviously note that $isUser and $isModerator are fake variables to make you understand the sense. You could either just check role value, once you got it.